# Will upgrading to Windows 10 replace my grub bootloader?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, bootloader, windows-10-upgrade

I dual-boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04. I have learned to install Windows before Ubuntu because the reverse results in having to finagle with a lot of settings to get the grub boot loader prompt back up instead of just automatically loading into Windows. Will the upgrade from within Windows 10 predictably do the same thing? If so, what is the straightforward way to getting grub back?

Comment: Yes; but all you do afterwords is repair it how you dual boot remains unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to repair grub after upgrading to Windows 10.

After you upgrade Windows, using a bootable Ubuntu USB or CD

Run it -> Install and run 'Boot repair' -> Recommended Repair

and reboot the system.

for more details, use these threads. 
[Thread1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) and [Thread2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly enough, the upgrade to 10 from 8.1 did not affect the current grub setup at all, which works for me!